# IntelliJ 14 clear console / terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, console

I have it setup to use cmd as the terminal but when I type cls or use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls")` I get a IOException saying Cannot run program "cls" the system cannot find the file specified.

Is there any way to keep native terminal commands within the embedded terminal in IntelliJ?

Comment: which platform are you running on and what's the cls command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("some command here")` will throw IOException if an I/O error occurs, and unknown command could cause the occurrence of this situation. 
that's to say `cls` command was not defined in the `PATH` environment at all.