# Can clear the intellij/pycharm console from within current program

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I'm have a long-running python script in Intellj/Pycharm. I'd like to be able to clear the Debug output console from time-to-time. Is this possible from within the program I'm running?

[IntelliJ 14 clear console / terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755053/intellij-14-clear-console-terminal)
(for Java), suggests running a shell command.
I tried this:

```
   assert os.system("clear")==0
```

which succeeds (if "emulate terminal in output console" is set in the run configuration), but it does not clear the console.

Comment: You would need to create a plug-in which clears the console and call the action of this plug-in from your code somehow, for example via jetbrains protocol: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56066943/104891.

Comment: Hmmm -- then I guess it doesn't emulate the terminal as advertised. There is a set of IPython APIs -- I wonder if those would help.